# Is there a way to add code to a method with AspectJ

Tags: java, runtime, aspectj

The problem is that I want to change the byte code of a method within a class.
Assume that we have this method:

```
public class Test{

  public Connection buildConnection(){
    Connection connection = null;
      if(connection==null){
        connection = Mysql.getConnection();
      }
      if(connection==null){
        throw new RunTimeException("Error");
      }
      return connection;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change this code at run time mode to match this below:

```
public class Test{

      public Connection buildConnection(){
        Connection connection = null;
          if(connection==null){
            connection = Mysql.getConnection();
          }else{
            connection = Oracle.getConnection();
          }
          if(connection==null){
            throw new RunTimeException("Error");
          }
          return connection;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that code you want to create is really what you want since connection is always null and you will always run just the first part of the if clause?  Did you instead mean if connection is still null after calling Mysql.getConnection() then it would call Oracle.getConnection() as a backup?